# Equating the coefficients of the following equation

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory

How to equate the coefficients of

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P(n,k)\frac{t^n}{n!}\frac{x^k}{k!}=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}Q(n)\frac{t^n}{n!}\frac{x^k}{k!}\right)^m.$$

I need to equate the coefficients of $\frac{t^n}{n!}\frac{x^k}{k!}$. How can we consider the coefficients $\left(\frac{t^n}{n!}\frac{x^k}{k!}\right)^m$ on the right hand side? Please give me an idea about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right hand side is $\frac{\sum_{kn}Q\frac{t^nx^k}{n!k!}}{1-\sum_{kn}Q\frac{t^nx^k}{n!k!}}$, so we want to solve$$\sum_{kn}Q\frac{t^nx^k}{n!k!}=\left(1-\sum_{kn}Q\frac{t^nx^k}{n!k!}\right)\sum_{k^\prime n^\prime}P\frac{t^{n^\prime}x^{k^\prime}}{n!k!}.$$Equating the $t^nx^k$ coefficient for $k\ge0,\,n\ge1$,$$\frac{Q(n)}{n!k!}=\frac{P(n,\,k)}{n!k!}-\sum_{k^\prime+k^{\prime\prime}=k,\,n^\prime+n^{\prime\prime}=n}\frac{Q(n^{\prime\prime})P(n^\prime,\,k^\prime)}{n^{\prime\prime}!k^{\prime\prime}!n^\prime!k^\prime!}.$$This is a recursion relation for $P$, viz.$$P(n,\,k)=Q(n)+\sum_{k^\prime+k^{\prime\prime}=k,\,n^\prime+n^{\prime\prime}=n}\binom{n}{n^\prime}\binom{k}{k^\prime}Q(n^{\prime\prime})P(n^\prime,\,k^\prime).$$